# cloudfront not working in laravel (using spatie/medialibrary)

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using S3 to store my images. I would like to have cloudfront or cloudflare deliver them.

I already set up a cloudfront link and tried to add it to the `'domain'` in medialibrary config (which previously was `'domain' = https://'.env('AWS_BUCKET').'.s3.amazonaws.com`.

It still delivers the images through the link `https://'.env('AWS_BUCKET').'.s3.amazonaws.com` and not through cloudfront. As if it doesn't register the change at all.

Not sure how to fix or debug this.

Comment: Apologies for mentioning this, but many cases have been solved by doing it; please make sure you've cleared your application cache: `php artisan config:cache && php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: @user8555937 I cleared the cache but it didn't help